# python list split convert to int and add

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
money = ['$130,000,000', '$27,000,000', '$36,000,000', '$52,000,000', '$45,010,000']
```

How can I split the list by `,` and `$`, int everything and add it?

Comment: You want to add `130 + 000 + 000`?

Answer (score 2):

You could strip the left dollar sign `$` with [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip), [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `,` into a list, [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the list back up, then convert to an `int` and calculate the total [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> money = ['$130,000,000', '$27,000,000', '$36,000,000', '$52,000,000', '$45,010,000']
>>> sum(int("".join(x.lstrip("$").split(","))) for x in money)
290010000
```

You could also format this into your original currency format using `:,` to split the number into thousands separated by `,`:

```
>>> '${:,}'.format(sum(int("".join(x.lstrip("$").split(","))) for x in money))
'$290,010,000'
```

Which goes into more detail at [PEP 378 -- Format Specifier for Thousands Separator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using regex:

```
sum([int(re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', m)) for m in money])
```

To explain ...

Using regex to strip out non digits from a string like `'$2,345,678'`:

```
import re
re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', '$2,345,678')
```

Apply it to `money` with list comprehension to get a new list:

```
[re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', m) for m in money]
```

Convert them to int:

```
[int(re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', m)) for m in money]
```

To add them, just pass it all to `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can code like this

```
money = ['$130,000,000', '$27,000,000', '$36,000,000', '$52,000,000', '$45,010,000']

sum=0

for i in money:

    sum=sum+int("".join((str(i).lstrip("$").split(","))))

print(sum)
```

Comment: `sum` is a builtin function in python. Not a good idea to override it with a variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You have to use the sum() function. But accidentally here I used sum as a variable not as function .